# Puting all vertex attributes of a scene into a single VBO

Tags: opengl-es2, vbo, vertex-attribute

I'm rendering various elements in OpenGL ES 2 on Android, and I'd like to pack the vertex attributes of the whole scene into a single vertex buffer object (VBO).

My question is, if these objects have different sets of attributes, strides and offsets, can I still pack this data into a single VBO and draw everything using it?

Most of these elements have 2 floats for position and 2 floats for texture coords (X, Y, S, T) as vertex attributes, and they do get drawn correctly using this:

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer.getBufferId());
    drawObject1();
    drawObject2();
    drawObject3();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

public void drawObject1() {
    glUseProgram(object1Program);
    object1Program.setUniforms(finalMatrixObject1, object1Texture);

    glVertexAttribPointer(object1Program.getPositionAttributeLocation(), 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 16, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(object1Program.getPositionAttributeLocation());
    glVertexAttribPointer(object1Program.getTextureCoordinatesAttributeLocation(), 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 16, 8);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(object1Program.getTextureCoordinatesAttributeLocation());

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}

public void drawObject2() {
    glUseProgram(object2Program);
    object2Program.setUniforms(finalMatrixObject2, object2Texture);

    glVertexAttribPointer(object2Program.getPositionAttributeLocation(), 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 16, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(object2Program.getPositionAttributeLocation());
    glVertexAttribPointer(object2Program.getTextureCoordinatesAttributeLocation(), 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 16, 8);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(object2Program.getTextureCoordinatesAttributeLocation());

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, 6);
}
```

But I have weird artifacts and coords showing (if at all) when I try to render an element with a different pattern of vertex attributes, for example just 2 floats for position (X Y), or 3 floats for position and 2 floats for texture coord (X Y Z S T).

```
public void drawObject3() {
    glUseProgram(object3Program);
    object3Program.setUniforms(finalMatrixObject3);

    glVertexAttribPointer(object3Program.getPositionAttributeLocation(), 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 8, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(object3Program.getPositionAttributeLocation());

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 12, 6);
}
```

To resume the situation, I have a VBO packed this way (it differs a bit from my previous example):

```
6 * (X, Y, S, T)
6 * (X, Y, S, T)
6 * (X, Y, S, T)
6 * (X, Y)
36 * (X, Y, Z, S, T)
```

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do? Or do I have to use different VBOs for every element with a unique set of vertex attributes?

If it's possible, what am I doing wrong? Before moving to VBO everything was working fine.

Comment: I think it is calculating the starting offset wrong. Try setting the last parameter of glVertexAttribPointer to 12 * 16 and the second of glDrawArrays to 0 instead of 12 in drawObject3. If that doesn't work you could also try 24 instead of 12 (but leave attribpointer at 0).

Comment: @Alex It's working, yeeees! If you can turn this into an answer (an explain it a bit more) I'll be happy to grant you the bounty. I need more explanation because object3 gets drawn now - with offset 12*16 (actually 18*16 in my example) and drawarrays 0 as first -, but when I try to follow the same logic, my object4 still gets artifacts, so I'm not getting it. BTW, thank you! :)

Comment: @Alex update: All objects working now and get drawn correctly. I still don't get why ´dataOffset´ and the "first vertex" param in ´glDrawArrays´ are working for the batch of first objects with the same set of attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were calculating the starting offsets into the buffer to render from incorrectly. The byte offset used is `pointer` + `first` * `stride`. When you call `glVertexAttribPointer` in `drawObject3` you set the `stride` to 8 and `pointer` to 0, so the offset is 8 * 12 which puts you at the start of your second row of data, not the row you expected. The easy way to do it correctly is to set `pointer` to where the data you want to render starts (18 * 16) and `first` to 0.

For the last row it would be 18 * 16 + 6 * 8.